# Loading session of an already existing selenium from another function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to load a website which I have already logged into from another function i.e. InitialCall().
But I am having problem with accessing the session which had already been loaded.
All answer I have seen keep pointing me to running a new selenium webdriver.
But I want to call the existing driver which is already active.

This is what I have done

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\direcorty\\where driver is stored ")  # this is the directory for the cookies

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('mail.websiteurl.com')

def initialCall():

    #othe login process takes place and continuation with admin page
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("5oead").get_attribute('innerHTML')
    #i tried saving the session here
    with open(path, 'w') as filehandler:
        json.dump(driver.get_cookies(), filehandler)
        
def callAlreadyLoggedSession():
    #chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\direcorty\\where driver is stored ")  # this is the directory for the cookies
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("5oead").get_attribute('innerHTML')
    #with open(path, 'r') as cookiesfile:
        #cookies = json.load(cookiesfile) 
        #for cookie in cookies:
            #print(cookie)
            #driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

The above code is loading another session which is closing the existing window, I would like it to directly access
the existing session without making use of a new window. Any help would be

**Update**

I have made some changes but a new problem had  commenced.
I have moved the selenium outside from inside a function to public, but it hangs the system and I cant use threading on it.

Comment: You've got the driver reference right there... no need to dump cookies or load them... just continue using "driver" to call methods.

Comment: @pcalkins Thank you very much. I have made some changes but a new problem had  commenced.

Comment: For threading you need one driver/browser pair per thread.  Those cannot share the same profile, so if there are cookies that can actually help preserve session (in most cases, no because they'd be marked as http-only...  Selenium can't read them, but you could do that outside Selenium) you'd need to save/load them.  You can attach two drivers to one thread, though, but it's going to be sequential driver actions.  Maybe you should describe more broadly what it is you are trying to do.